# Swap collections during events handling

Tags: c#, events, collections, locking

I am trying to implement `ObservationStorage` class, which should save data to proper collection depends on current `YearMonthDay`. Requests of new observations comes to my storage object by events that are handled by `OnDataOccured` methods.

```
public class ObserversDataStorage : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private object _lock = new object();

    public Dictionary<YearMonthDay, DailyObserverStorage> Storage { get; set; }

    public ObserversDataStorage()
    {
        this.Storage = new Dictionary<YearMonthDay, DailyObserverStorage>();
    }

    public void OnDataOccured(object sender, Common.Observer.AbstractQueryResult e)
    {
        var ymd = YearMonthDay.FromUTCMiliseconds(e.From);

        if (this.Storage.Keys.Contains(ymd))
        {
            this.Storage[ymd].OnDataOccured(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Storage.Add(ymd, new DailyObserverStorage(ymd));
            this.Storage[ymd].OnDataOccured(sender, e);
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<YearMonthDay, DailyObserverStorage> ChangeStorage()
    {
        Dictionary<YearMonthDay, DailyObserverStorage> toReturn;            
        lock (_lock)
        {
            toReturn = this.Storage;
            this.Storage = new Dictionary<YearMonthDay, DailyObserverStorage>();
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

My question is: 
How should I implement `ChangeStorage` method in order to prevent null pointer exception while handling `OnDataOccured` request?

I tried above implementation but I am not sure whether it is save enough.

Comment: Right now you only make sure that ChageStorage only can be call from one thread at a time. You need a lock in OnDataOccured as well to ensure that data cannot be read and written at the same time

Comment: So I need to ensure that all methods, which are using my `this.Storage` collection should use lock mechanism. Am I right?

Comment: You can use [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297966(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, you basically need to make the Dictionary thread safe.